Getting number of pixels in raster layer with valid data in QGIS
In QGIS 3, how do I get the number of pixels in a raster layer with valid data?

You've asked 16 questions but never accepted an answer: What should I do when someone answers my question?

Use the Raster Layer Statistics tool. The output report includes a count of non-NoData pixels (tested in QGIS 3.40):
Parameters:

Output log:

Text of OUTPUT_HTML_FILE.html:
Analyzed file: raster.tif (band 1)
Count of non-NoData pixels: 41543769   <===== valid pixel count
Minimum value: 10722
Maximum value: 24631
Range: 13909
Sum: 490624577348
Mean value: 11809.82345025075
Standard deviation: 358.0939379390351
Sum of the squares: 5327210064285.286


Unfortunately, I do not get a "Count of non-NoData pixels" line in the output...

I'd add a screenshot of the output, but can't figure out how.

Edit question, add your screenshot using the image button in the toolbar, also please include details about the raster (right-click > layer properties > Information > Information from provider) and  what version of QGIS used.
